# How do I cross reference other docsets with Doxygen

Tags: objective-c, xcode, doxygen

I have succeeded in creating a docset for my custom Cocoa Touch Static Library project using Doxygen. I can place links to other classes and members within the scope of my library project, but I cannot find a way to make (clickable) references to other frameworks, especially UIKit or NSFoundation.

This is an example of my documentation comments:

```
/**
 If #shouldLoadDataFromTableEntriesJSONFile returns YES, this method
 will be asked to provide the full path to the appropriate JSON file.

 @return an absolute path to a JSON file. 

 @see MyOtherClass#aMethodThere
 @see NSBundle#mainBundle  
*/
```

Doxygen correctly creates a hyperlink to the `shouldLoadDataFromTableEntriesJSONFile` within that same class and to `aMethodThere` in `MyOtherClass`, but not to `NSBundle#mainBundle`. I understand that this might be more difficult, because it is located elsewhere, but can I set it up in a way to tell it how to do this? 
Any special flags or variable defintions required that I am missing or is it merely a question of how to formulate it in the doc comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just saw this (I had the same question). I have a not so ideal answer which might help: [Linking to Apple (or 3rd party) documentation tokens in a docset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465758/linking-to-apple-or-3rd-party-documentation-tokens-in-a-docset)